# Bug using wp_insert_term with switch_to_blog

Tags: taxonomy, terms, switch-to-blog

I'm running a network of about 80 sites using WP multisite 3.2. I'm experiencing irregularities using switch_to_blog whith wp_insert_term.

To test this I have disabled all plugins, and am testing on a blank page so nothing else interferes. This is the sample code:

```
switch_to_blog(75);
wp_insert_term( 'New Term','category');
restore_current_blog();
```

When run from *most blogs* it adds the new term to the desired blog and the permalink to the new term page works.

But for a few of the blogs, when it runs it adds the term, but the link to the new term page throws a 404 error. Opening wp-admin and adding any new term through wp-admin fixes it.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Hook into `'pre_insert_term', $term, $taxonomy` and dump the global `$blog_id;` to see if you're on the right place:

```
function wpse_inspect_blog_id( $term, $taxonomy )
{
    global $blog_id;
    var_dump( $blog_id );
    exit;
}
function wpse_hook_inspector_blog_id()
{
    add_filter( 'pre_insert_term', 'wpse_inspect_blog_id' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_hook_inspector_blog_id' );
```